# How to preserve HTML from posts in RSS feed

Tags: posts, rss, feed

I have set up a sample post with a few different HTML tags. This is the markup, copied from the block editor:

```
<!-- wp:columns -->
<div class="wp-block-columns"><!-- wp:column -->
<div class="wp-block-column"><!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>This is paragraph 1.</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->

<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>In a new paragraph, we begin an unordered list:</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->

<!-- wp:list -->
<ul><li>list item 1</li><li>list item 2</li><li>list item 3</li></ul>
<!-- /wp:list -->

<!-- wp:image {"id":418,"sizeSlug":"full","linkDestination":"none"} -->
<figure class="wp-block-image size-full"><img src="https://domain.tld/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/logo.png" alt="" class="wp-image-418"/><figcaption>organization logo</figcaption></figure>
<!-- /wp:image -->

<!-- wp:html -->
Begin custom HTML
<br><hr><a href="#">link trial</a><br>
<div><p>This is a paragraph in a div</div>
<!-- /wp:html -->

<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>Each</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->

<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>of</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->

<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>these</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->

<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>words</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->

<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>is</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->

<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>a</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->

<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>paragraph</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph --></div>
<!-- /wp:column --></div>
<!-- /wp:columns -->
```

Checking on my feed, it shows `description` and `content:encoded` elements like the following:

```
<description><![CDATA[This is an excerpt]]></description>
<content:encoded><![CDATA[<p>This is paragraph 1. In a new paragraph, we begin an unordered list: list item 1 list item 2 list item 3 Begin custom HTML link trial This is a paragraph in a div Each of these words is a paragraph...</p>
<p><a href="https://domain.tld/sample/" rel="nofollow">Source</a></p>]]></content:encoded>
```

Obviously some mechanism is stripping all the HTML and wrapping the plaintext of the post in a single `<p>` - but I'm struggling to find what it is.

I placed a `print_debug_backtrace()` at the top of `feed-rss2.php` and got the following:

```
#0  require_once() called at [/home1/foo/public_html/wp-includes/template.php:770]
#1  load_template(/home1/foo/public_html/wp-includes/feed-rss2.php) called at [/home1/foo/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php:1623]
#2  do_feed_rss2() called at [/home1/foo/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:305]
#3  WP_Hook->apply_filters(, Array ([0] => ,[1] => rss2)) called at [/home1/foo/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:327]
#4  WP_Hook->do_action(Array ([0] => ,[1] => rss2)) called at [/home1/foo/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php:470]
#5  do_action(do_feed_rss2, , rss2) called at [/home1/foo/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php:1585]
#6  do_feed() called at [/home1/foo/public_html/wp-includes/template-loader.php:48]
#7  require_once(/home1/foo/public_html/wp-includes/template-loader.php) called at [/home1/foo/public_html/wp-blog-header.php:19]
#8  require(/home1/foo/public_html/wp-blog-header.php) called at [/home1/foo/public_html/index.php:17]
```

I have also set up a custom debug page and stepped through what I observed as the call stack of the `<content:encoded>` element. Those tests all came back with the desired HTML and none of the WP content comments.

Appreciate any help you all can send my way

Addendum: The end goal here is to enable MailChimp's RSS merge to pick up these posts and send them, collectively, in a periodic email without the need to duplicate efforts. I'm aware of the limitations of HTML in email, all posts will be extremely simple markup but I want at least to have paragraph breaks.
I'm pretty sure my use case obviates using the API.
With the markup being wrapped in `CDATA` I don't expect to run afoul of RSS validation.

.

Comment: if you're trying too syndicate you might be better using the posts REST API endpoint rather than the RSS feed, you'll get the direct HTML both raw and rendered, as well as all posts, not just what the feed gives you and in JSON not XML. Your HTML with the block html comments is raw unprocessed and won't have any server side rendered blocks etc or shortcodes

Comment: a lot of blocks output HTML markup that shouldn't go in RSS content, which is likely why it's being filtered out, that's intended behaviour. What are you trying to do that requires this?

Comment: Edited question to incorporate responses to comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this behavior was being caused by a plug-in with a default setting to convert all posts into excerpts, thereby stripping the markup.

I determined this by standing up a stock WordPress instance with none of my customizations or theme, replicating the installed plug-ins (just their existence, not their settings), and checking the feed after activating each of them.

The moral of the story is that you'll miss a lot of behaviors and waste a lot of time tinkering with code and not focusing on replicating the behavior.

Comment: I am having the same problem - the raw HTML is stripped in my RSS feed. Could you tell me which plugin caused this problem?

Comment: @KatyKauffman I do not recall which plugin it was at this point and it is a behavior that could be added by nearly and plug-in. I strongly recommend that you try disabling each of your plug-ins, one at a time, and reloading your RSS feed in a browser window to identify which of yours is causing the problem